# ob_end_flush error when using wpdb in plugin

Tags: plugins, wpdb

I created a small plugin to test database interactions in wordpress. I have a small function that inputs the arguments to the table.

If i call my function in a themefile it inputs my test values to my table, but if i call it from another plugin i get this error:

Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0) in /.../wp-includes/functions.php on line 2504

I have no idea what this error means, can anyone shed some light on it?

edit: I use MAMP with PHP 5.4.4

edit2:

```
function test_db_function($name, $message){
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "testDB";

  if( $name == '' || $message == '' || !isset($name) || !isset($message)) {
    //return 0;
  }
  else{
    $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
      'time' => time(), 
      'name' => $name, 
      'text' => $message) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not provide that information, so I have to guess a little bit: You are using PHP 5.4 and `zlib.output_compression` is `on` on your server?

Then you just stumbled upon [bug #18525](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18525). Possible solutions:

- Disable `zlib.output_compression`.
- Apply the patch provided there and *report back on that ticket if it works*.
- Disable notices.

What you can do when you decide to release the plugin to the public is another issue …

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, realized i provided a little information. I use PHP 5.4.4 in MAMP.

Comment: I see that bug happens on auto-updates of plugins. I get the notice when calling a function from my plugin, and the function is not performed.

Comment: Same problem here - I found that adding `ini_set('zlib.output_handler', '');` at the top of my plugin solved it.